# Are there updates regarding the new SE-site design coming to worldbuilding?

Tags: discussion

I have read a few things about the new site themes and tried to follow the updates, but I have not yet read anything whether our ["Save the Robot!"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6397/44086) campaign has been heard or not.

[Shortly, the new site theme is to be rolled out on "beta and undesigned" sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315662/397029) Which does (probably) not include Worldbuilding, as it is neither Beta and is quite obviously designed.

#### Are there any news regarding the site theme for worldbuilding?

I did not manage to find anything on Meta.SE. Except for that [plan in June](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/397029) was

> August - September: release to the remaining sites. As we have more details we will update individual communities in their local meta.

September is not over yet, but I have not read anything about Worldbuilding up until now.

Comment: The [tracking post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979/162102) says they haven't yet started on Worldbuilding, but I too hope we can get an answer about the robot before they roll out a design.

Comment: Unfortunately, they're probably going to apply it eventually.

Comment: Not just obviously designed, but quite beautifully designed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the new meta post [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/worldbuildings-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing).

Yes, we’re keeping the robot! Congrats and thank you to everyone who ran that campaign.

Comment: Thanks for adding this as an answer to the post!